# How to write a plugin or script for Kate that takes a unicode code point and inserts the corresponding unicode character at cursor?

Tags: unicode, plugin, kate

Entering arbitrary Unicode characters according to their code point is simple e.g. in Gedit (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>, enter the (hex) code point, press enter).

One can even use the terminal. For example, executing `echo -e '\u2603'` produces a snowman, ☃. Here 2603 is, again, the code point in hex.

KDE's Kate, however, currently (as of Version 19.12.3) does not seem to have similar functionality.

True, one can use Gedit or the terminal to produce the symbol, which can then be copied and pasted into Kate. But this is awkward.

At the same time, Kate does support plugins and scripts. Unfortunately, I have not been able to find any tutorials for how to write them (except [this one](https://kate-editor.org/2004/01/06/writing-a-kate-plugin/), from 2004, which is so terse that it hardly qualifies as a tutorial, and anyway is probably obsolete).

It would be nice if the plugin were to implement the same functionality as Gedit, since its method of entering Unicode characters seems to be a pretty standard way to do it.

But it doesn't have to be done that way. Maybe the Kate plugin (or Kate script?) could work like this: upon pressing a keyboard shortcut, a standard KDE pop-up dialog appears, prompting you to enter the Unicode hex code. Once the code is entered, we press 'enter', and the corresponding Unicode character is inserted at the current location of the cursor in Kate.

No doubt there are other methods of entering that would make sense. The key is that the Unicode character must be entered at the current location of the cursor.

Is something like this possible to do in Kate using plugins (or scripts)? How difficult might it be to write the appropriate plugin (or script)? How would one go about writing and installing such a plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried **KCharSelect**? You can search a symbol you need there, then copy it to clipboard, then paste to the Kate.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, I do use KCharSelect. However, while this answer may be useful to people who didn't know about that program, it doesn't answer my question as posed, which really emphasized expanding the functionality of Kate using scripts or plugins.

Comment: Why exactly you want it to be a _kate_ plugin and not system wide possibility? I mean, it may be also useful in other places to enter a symbol by its unicode number.

Comment: On the one hand, if someone explained how to implement a system-wide capability to insert a unicode symbol at the current cursor position by means of a keyboard shortcut plus a unicode number (and without cutting and pasting), that I would at least upvote. ([This](https://askubuntu.com/a/1095581) comes close, but is not quite it.) On the other hand, I might want to extend Kate's functionality in other ways, so an example like the one I'm asking for here would be useful in that respect.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from version 21.12, Kate comes with a latex completion plugin that should be able to provide this functionality.

https://github.com/KDE/kate/tree/master/addons/latexunicodecompletion

The plugin can be enabled in the settings. Once the plugin is enabled, open a new file and then type "\u" followed by whatever symbol you are looking for.

[image: img]

---

#### Doing this with a script

```
var katescript = {
    "author": "name <email>",
    "license": "LGPLv2+",
    "revision": 1,
    "kate-version": "5.1",
    "functions": ["do_my_stuff"],
    "actions": [
        {   "function": "do_my_stuff",
            "name": "User visible name of the action",
            "category": "Editing",
            "shortcut": "Ctrl+Shift+A",
            "interactive": "false"
        }
    ]
};

require("range.js");
require("cursor.js");

function help(cmd) {
    if (cmd == "do_my_stuff") return i18n("Does xyz");
    return "";
}

function isCursorOnUnicode() {
    // code to check 
    return Range();
}

function do_my_stuff() {
    debug(document.mimeType());

    var range = isCursorOnString();
    if (!range.isValid()) {
        return;
    }

    var text = document.text(range);
    if (text == "")
        return;

    document.editBegin();

    var insertText = "...";
    document.insertText(range.start, insertText);
    var endCur = range.end;
    endCur.setPosition(endCur.line, endCur.column + insertText.length);
    document.insertText(endCur, ")");

    document.editEnd();
}
```

The above script doesn't actually do anything but shows how you can write a script that will be able to do what you want. The script supports ECMAScript version 6 so types like Set are available for use.

The most important part of the script is its header at the top `var katescript = {...`. Kate will use this header to make your script work. In this header you specify the function that will be executed once you run your script. In our case this function is `"function": "do_my_stuff"`. You can have other functions as well but they won't be visible in the UI.

How to invoke the script?

MenuBar -> Tools -> Scripts -> Editing -> YOUR_SCRIPT_NAME

This can be tedious, so another way to do it would be to hit `F7` and then type the name of the function i.e., `do_my_stuff` and your script will be invoked.

As you probably already have noticed, you can also invoke the script with a shortcut. In this case the shortcut is `Ctrl+Shift+A`, but you can change it to anything else as long as it doesn't conflict with another shortcut.

You can find the documentation on all available functions exposed by Kate here: https://docs.kde.org/stable5/en/kate/katepart/dev-scripting.html

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: My version of Kate (and probably of Qt) is not high enough to test this. However, if you provide more details, I might be able to conclude that this answers the question.

Comment: @linguisticturn I updated the answer to show how the plugin is used. Also added how you can do this with a script.